# Can i get all the Vector2Ints from an Boundsint? C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to have all of the cells in a Tilemap into an array, I've tried:

```
Vector3Int[] Example = Examplemap.cellBounds
```

but that didn't work. Please help me

Comment: well don't you already have them all?  if `cellBounds` is the boundry of the tile map then your `Vector2Int` are literally every value between `cellBounds.xMin - > cellBounds.xMax` and `cellBounds.yMin -> cellBounds.yMax`...

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if i can use that

Comment: Ok sorry I don't understand how to use that, can you provide an example of how I can get all the Vector2ints from the cell bounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate over `Tilemap.cellBounds.allPositionsWithin` which should return `BoundsInt` in each loop. Use the [`HasTile`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.HasTile.html) to check if there is a tile that position in the `Tilemap`. If there is a tile in that position, use `Tilemap.CellToWorld` to covert the position to world then add it to a `List`.

```
List<Vector3> GetCellsFromTilemap(Tilemap tilemap)
{
    List<Vector3> worldPosCells = new List<Vector3>();
    foreach (var boundInt in tilemap.cellBounds.allPositionsWithin)
    {
        //Get the local position of the cell
        Vector3Int relativePos = new Vector3Int(boundInt.x, boundInt.y, boundInt.z);
        //Add it to the List if the local pos exist in the Tile map
        if (tilemap.HasTile(relativePos))
        {
            //Convert to world space
            Vector3 worldPos = tilemap.CellToWorld(relativePos);
            worldPosCells.Add(worldPos);
        }
    }
    return worldPosCells;
}
```

To use:

```
Tilemap Examplemap = ...;
List<Vector3> cells = GetCellsFromTilemap(Examplemap);
```

---

If you prefer the cell positions to be returned in local space, replace `tilemap.CellToWorld(relativePos)` with `tilemap.CellToLocal(relativePos)`.

```
List<Vector3> GetCellsFromTilemap(Tilemap tilemap)
{
    List<Vector3> worldPosCells = new List<Vector3>();
    foreach (var boundInt in tilemap.cellBounds.allPositionsWithin)
    {
        //Get the local position of the cell
        Vector3Int relativePos = new Vector3Int(boundInt.x, boundInt.y, boundInt.z);
        //Add it to the List if the local pos exist in the Tile map
        if (tilemap.HasTile(relativePos))
        {
            //Convert to world space
            Vector3 localPos = tilemap.CellToLocal(relativePos);
            worldPosCells.Add(localPos);
        }
    }
    return worldPosCells;
}
```

---

Finally, if you just want the `Vector2Ints` with no conversion then just add the data from the loop directly to the `List`:

```
List<Vector3Int> GetCellsFromTilemap(Tilemap tilemap)
{
    List<Vector3Int> cells = new List<Vector3Int>();
    foreach (var boundInt in tilemap.cellBounds.allPositionsWithin)
    {
        //Get the local position of the cell
        Vector3Int relativePos = new Vector3Int(boundInt.x, boundInt.y, boundInt.z);
        //Add it to the List if the local pos exist in the Tile map
        if (tilemap.HasTile(relativePos))
            cells.Add(relativePos);
    }
    return cells;
}
```